# How to prevent my regex pattern from seperating a string and putting them into groups?

Tags: python, regex, list, replace

I have a list which consists of different strings and my regex code is separating a string in two groups if the other group is found empty.

```
A=['ABNo/2017','ABno/20/2017','ABNo461 /17','ABNo/20/17']
```

My code:

```
A=['ABNo/2017','ABno/20/2017','ABNo461 /17','ABNo/20/17']
newlist=[]
pattern = r"\b(AB)\D*(\d+)\s?\S*(\d\d)\b"
for i in A:
    m = re.search(pattern,i)
    if m==None or m.group(3)==None:
        newlist.append('')
    else:
        newlist.append(m.group(1)+'/'+m.group(2)+'/'+m.group(3))
newlist
```

```
Output I'm getting:
['AB/20/17', 'AB/20/17', 'AB/461/17', 'AB/20/17']
```

```
Expected Output:
['', 'AB/20/17', 'AB/461/17', 'AB/20/17']
```

Basically what I want is group 2 should read all the numbers if there are no symbols between the numbers and group 3 should remain empty in that case.
AB/2017 should be read as group(1) as AB, group(2) as digits(2017) and group(3) should match None. And if group 3 is None I have appended '' in list.

Comment: You need an explicit non-digit in addition to `\s?\S*`

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: I want you to think about it very carefully and experiment for yourself before I hand you the answer

Comment: I have added \s?\S* because between ABNo.261(or anynumber i want)/23/45/HDB/2017.
i.e ABNo.261/23/45/HDB/2017. Anything could be there after AB No. xxx and before last 2 digits of year.

Comment: I can't think of anything else

Comment: Okay I have added a \b after (\d+) it works now

Comment: Very nice. Now you can post an answer

Answer (score 0):

Adding a word boundary after (\d+) works.
pattern = r"\b(AB)\D*(\d+)\b\s?\S*(\d\d)\b"